# Django Syntax Error while Attempting SubURL's

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm not only new to Django but also Python.I'm following a video tutorial in my native language; however while applying instructions, I got following error:

```
> Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f6b2477eae8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/stockfish/Masaüstü/DjangoOne/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/stockfish/Masaüstü/DjangoOne/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/stockfish/Masaüstü/DjangoOne/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/stockfish/Masaüstü/DjangoOne/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/stockfish/Masaüstü/DjangoOne/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 73, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/stockfish/Masaüstü/DjangoOne/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/stockfish/Masaüstü/DjangoOne/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/stockfish/Masaüstü/DjangoOne/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 397, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/stockfish/Masaüstü/DjangoOne/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/stockfish/Masaüstü/DjangoOne/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 536, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/stockfish/Masaüstü/DjangoOne/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/stockfish/Masaüstü/DjangoOne/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 529, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/stockfish/Masaüstü/DjangoOne/DjangoKod/urls.py", line 25, in <module>
    re_path(r'^post/', include('post.urls')),
  File "/home/stockfish/Masaüstü/DjangoOne/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 674, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 781, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 741, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/stockfish/Masaüstü/DjangoOne/post/urls.py", line 6
    re_path(r'^detail/$', PostDetail)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I should note that video tutorials are made in a previous version of Django (As far as i remember DjangoVer=1.9); however I'm using the newest versions of both Python and Django.

As an example: In one of the videos the instructor uses something like:

```
url(r'^$', HomeView)
```

But it wasn't correct for my version.I have done some research and noticed that I'm supposed to use 're_path' instead of 'url' for the newer version of Django and corrected it. (Right?)

As a conclusion:

1) How can I fix the last error?
2) How can I get simple and effective guidance for Django? Django's main website looks a little bit complicated to me.(It's really a shame to keep people busy here whenever I get stuck.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the urls.py?

Comment: You are probably missing a comma at the end of the previous line in the list of URLs.

Comment: @Rakesh: This is the urls.py which belongs to PostApp: from django.urls import include, path, re_path
from post.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^index/$', PostIndex)
    re_path(r'^detail/$', PostDetail)
    re_path(r'^create/$', PostCreate)
    re_path(r'^update/$', PostUpdate)
    re_path(r'^delete/$', PostDelete)
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in urls.py. The Comma are missing in `urlpatterns`

**Ex:**

```
from django.urls import include, path, re_path
from post.views import *
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^index/$', PostIndex),
    re_path(r'^detail/$', PostDetail),
    re_path(r'^create/$', PostCreate), 
    re_path(r'^update/$', PostUpdate),
    re_path(r'^delete/$', PostDelete)
]
```

Comment: Thank you Rakesh! ;) I have no idea how i missed this, those commas are exist in the tutorial :s By the way, do you have any suggestions for learning django in an effective and easy way? It would help me a lot.